# Ajax call to get remote file only returns part of file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, resources

I have an ajax call to get a remote file on my server. It works, but only returns part of the file:

```
var remoteFile;
$.ajax({  
            async: false,
            url: "http;//myAWSDNS.com/some/path/file.txt",  
            dataType: "text",  
            success: function(data) { 
            remoteFile = data; 
            }  
            });
      .
      .
      .
      //more code
```

I have confirmed that the file currently looks like this:

```
user,   wants to pair with

user1, test@gmail.com
user2, anothertest@gmail.com
```

however, in code, `remoteFile` only is this:

```
user,   wants to pair with

user1, test@gmail.com
```

i.e. it is missing the last line.
Why can this be happening? Is it a JavaScript string issue, or an ajax issue?

Thanks,

best regards,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Try changing datatype to text/plain

Comment: Hey Nav, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, changing dataType to text/plain broke it more, since remoteFile turned out to be undefined after that change. The weirdest thing is that now that I changed it back to "text", it actually works as I wanted it to work from the start. Funny. Anyway, your suggestion led me to the (not-understood-by-me) solution. Thanks! ;)

Comment: No probs as long as it works I guess all the best :)

Comment: And the issue is back again. Now, after having used the current data type text successfully for a while, it is back to the behaviour where for some reason remoteFile only has part of the contents of the remote file. Any idea why, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Actually how we're u checking the response? Where writing it to the screen or an alert?

Comment: i was checking it with the javascript console in chrome, so inspecting directly via mouse hovering